# C++ v100 platform toolset profiler

Tags: c++, memory, profiler

I am looking for a profiler for C++ project build in Visual Studio and compiled with v100 platform toolset

I got memory leak when my application is running (memory usage is increasing).

When i exit the program i do not see any memory leaks (I use VLD)

Answer (score 0):

If you’re using `new` in your application, you should use the [debug version of `new`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz7sxz99.aspx). Add the following line at the beginning of your files (but after `#include "stdafx.h"`):

```
//...
#define new DEBUG_NEW
//...
```

If the memory allocation number that you're seeing in the output window has always the same number, regardless of how many times you're running the application, you can [set a break-point on allocation number](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx):

```
Output Window:
...
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
your file path (line number where new was called) : {allocation number}
...
```

Comment: Thx,

The thing is that the code is a very old code that uses, new, maloc, caloc and more methods 

I will try DEBUG_NEW and update later on the results

Comment: @NachumShmilovitz I would replace `malloc & calloc/free` with `new/delete/smart-pointers`, if possible.

Comment: Thx, 
We have ~ 100 places to change, so it is not so bad